# GIT : deleted files remotely, not updated online

Tags: git

I ran the following steps:

git remote add origin https://github.com/.../...
Then I deleted files locally and then updated them remotely.
But I can still find the original files along with new files (from remote server) in the online repository.

So my original files did not get deleted.
How can I solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`git add . && git commit -m <message> && git push`.

You probably failed to commit *deleting* the files. If a file shows up as red in `git status`, that means other people won't see that change when you commit and push. So fix this with `git add .` or `git rm deleted.txt`.

Comment: Thanks! I did a push and commit using android studio, and not using git bash. But amazingly this worked.